# Firebase Firestore not working in my Service class

Tags: java, android, service, google-cloud-firestore

The same working code for firebase written in an Activity class does not execute in the Service class that I have created. It just skips the onComplete callback and doesn't update any fields in firebase.

My Code in my Service class:

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
        
    
        @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
           execute();
            stopSelf();
        }
        public void execute(){
            final FirebaseFirestore database=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            final SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


 database.collection("users").whereEqualTo("username",shared.getString("username","")).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                 
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("online", false);
                                database.collection("users").document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());
                          
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

**NOTE: onTaskRemoved() is being called so you don't have to have any doubts regarding this.**

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document...` and run the code in a debugger, does it hit that breakpoint?

Comment: If you mean by breakpoint Logcat code, then yes I did. That's why there is a space before the for loop, I was trying to erase them before posting lol. It just doesn't print out anything.

Comment: could it be that the service is terminating before the execution of the firebase code since firebase works asynchronously?

Comment: Ah, I missed this runs in a `Service`. You might want to check when `onTaskRemoved` gets called in that case. I'd leave the log calls in the code when you post, and then also share their output from logcat. That ensures we see the same thing as you see, without running your code. To learn about breakpoints, I recommend reading on https://developer.android.com/studio/debug and specifically https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints

Comment: onTaskRemoved gets called when I kill the process of my app. The problem doesn't lie on whether it is being called or not, firebase code does not run in the entire Service class. In the case written in my post, code execution reaches just before database.collection() and 'jumps' all over the firebase code reaching the end of the callback function.

Comment: That is normal. Since the loading of data happens asynchronously, execution is not sequential here. Hence my request to set a breakpoint (or show your logging output), which will show the actual execution order. If your `onComplete` never gets called, add an `onFailure` handler.